# Return next full second based on current time

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I am trying to create a function that will return next full second, but looking through the c++11 `std::chrono` documentation I cannot find any obvious way to accomplish that.

Example: If the current time is `09:50:01.1234` I want the function to return `09:50:02.0000`(i.e. the next full second).

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point return_next_full_second()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();

    system_clock::time_point next_full_second = // How? 

    return next_full_second;
}
```

**Any hints on how to accomplish this, if at all possible using `std::chrono` ?**

My goal I want to achieve is to perform a specific action, at as close to every full second as possible. So I will be using the result to sleep for a duration of `return_next_full_second() - system_clock::now()`.

Comment: Here are some useful chrono rounding functions for durations which could be used to solve this problem: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_util.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might do a duration cast to seconds:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point return_next_full_second()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
    auto s = duration_cast<seconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
    return system_clock::time_point(++s);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t = return_next_full_second();
    auto d = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t.time_since_epoch());
    std::cout <<  d.count() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I don't get the last cast in ms from t - epoch.. care to explain?

Comment: @MarcoA. To see that the results holds seconds (3 zeros at the end)

Comment: Got it, thanks. This is a better solution, may I edit it a bit? There's also a grammar typo

Comment: @MarcoA. ctime represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch (hence the rollback)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `time_t` object using the static `system_clock::to_time_t` method.

`time_t` is usually "seconds since epoch so it is already rounded to seconds.

Then you can use `system_clock::from_time_t` to get a `system_clock::time_point` object back from the `time_t`.

To make sure that `to_time_t` really rounds *up* just compare the rounded time point to the initial time point. If it is less than that time point, just add a second.

The only problem with this solution is that `time_t` is not strictly defined to be in seconds, so the solution might not be portable.

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping for a portable solution, but if non exist I will use this approach.